# Attached properties/events

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a question regarding custom attached properties/events. In my scenario I want to attach a property/event to any control. The value of this property/event should be an event handler. In short, it should look like:

```xml
<TextBox local:Dragging.OnDrag="OnDrag" />
```

First I tried to implement OnDrag as an attached property. This works for the case above, but then the following case fails:

```xml
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="local:Dragging.OnDrag" Value="OnDrag" />
</Style>
```

Because the "OnDrag" string can apparently not be made into a RoutedEventHandler (the attached property's type) by the XAML system.

The next thing I tried then was to try and use an attached event, very much like the builtin Mouse.MouseEnter for example.

The complete code for this is shown at the bottom. There are curious things happening with this version:

1. If you run the code as shown (with the RegisterRoutedEvent line commented) it will show the "Add handler" function is called. Then the xaml system has an internal exception when applying the style (due to missing registered event I guess).
2. If you run the code with the RegisterRoutedEvent line in effect everything runs, but the "Add handler" function is never called. I want it to be called though, so that I can register at the drag and drop manager.
3. Curiously, if I change the event in the EventSetter from my own to Mouse.MouseEnter the code that's automatically generated by the xaml designer (in MainWindow.g[.i].cs) is different.

I am not sure why 2) does not call the AddXYZHandler. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613550.aspx) seems to indicate this should work.

Finally my questions:

1. How can I make this work? Is it possible at all?
2. Do I better use an attached event or an attached property for my scenario?
3. in case of properties: How do I fix the Style Setter so it converts the OnDrag string to a proper RoutedEventHandler?
4. in case of events: What's going wrong here? Any way to fix this? I want AddXYZHandler to be called, but apparently that does not work with the style.

MainWindow.xaml:

```xml
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        x:Class="GridTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GridTest"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        local:XYZTest.XYZ="OnXYZAttached">
    <Window.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Window">
            <EventSetter Event="local:XYZTest.XYZ" Handler="OnXYZStyle" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Style>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```cs
using System.Windows;

namespace GridTest
{
    public class XYZTest
    {
        //public static readonly RoutedEvent XYZEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("XYZ", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(XYZTest));

        public static void AddXYZHandler(DependencyObject element, RoutedEventHandler handler)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("add handler");
        }

        public static void RemoveXYZHandler(DependencyObject element, RoutedEventHandler handler)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("remove handler");
        }
    }

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void OnXYZAttached(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("attached");
        }

        public void OnXYZStyle(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("style");
        }
    }
}
```

}

---

New code:

```xml
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        x:Class="GridTest.MainWindow"
        x:Name="root"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GridTest"
        local:XYZTest.ABC="OnXYZTopLevel"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                <Setter Property="local:XYZTest.ABC" Value="OnXYZStyle" /> 
                <!-- <Setter Property="local:XYZTest.ABC" Value="{Binding OnXYZStyleProperty, ElementName=root}" /> -->
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListBox>
</Window>
```

```cs
using System.Windows;

namespace GridTest
{
    public class XYZTest
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ABCProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ABC", typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(XYZTest), new UIPropertyMetadata(null, OnABCChanged));

        public static void SetABC(UIElement element, RoutedEventHandler value)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ABC set to " + value.Method.Name);
        }

        static void OnABCChanged(DependencyObject depObj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ABC changed to " + ((RoutedEventHandler)e.NewValue).Method.Name);
        }
    }

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new[] { "A", "B", "C" };
        }

        public void OnXYZTopLevel(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("handler top level");
        }

        public void OnXYZStyle(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("handler style");
        }

        public RoutedEventHandler OnXYZStyleProperty
        {
            get { return OnXYZStyle; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I did a copy/paste from the Microsoft example, and it didn't work. They never specified what "WPF base class" to derive from, but I used DependencyObject, and it never even called Add*Handler.

Answer (score 2):

I successfully implemented drag and drop functionality completely using `Attached Properties`. If I were you, I'd avoid using custom events for this, as you're stuck with their parameters. Personally, I went for `ICommand` instead, but you could also use `delegate`s.

Please look below at the list of properties and `Command`s that I used in my drag and drop base class implementation:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the type of the drag and drop object required by the Control that the property is set on.
/// </summary>
public Type DragDropType { get; set; }

/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the allowable types of objects that can be used in drag and drop operations.
/// </summary>
public List<Type> DragDropTypes { get; set; }

/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the ICommand instance that will be executed when the user attempts to drop a dragged item onto a valid drop target Control.
/// </summary>
public ICommand DropCommand { get; set; }

/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the DragDropEffects object that specifies the type of the drag and drop operations allowable on the Control that the property is set on.
/// </summary>
public DragDropEffects DragDropEffects { get; set; }

/// <summary>
/// The Point struct that represents the position on screen that the user initiated the drag and drop procedure.
/// </summary>
protected Point DragStartPosition
{
    get { return dragStartPosition; }
    set { if (dragStartPosition != value) { dragStartPosition = value; } }
}

/// <summary>
/// The UIElement object that represents the UI element that has the attached Adorner control... usually the top level view.
/// </summary>
protected UIElement AdornedUIElement
{
    get { return adornedUIElement; }
    set { if (adornedUIElement != value) { adornedUIElement = value; } }
}
```

The `AdornedUIElement` property holds an `Adorner` that displays the dragged items as they are dragged, but is optional for you to implement. In this base class, I have implemented most of the drag and drop functionality and exposed `protected abstract` methods that derived classes must implement. As an example, this method calls the `OnAdornedUIElementPreviewDragOver` method to provide derived classes an opportunity to change the behaviour of the base class:

```
private void AdornedUIElementPreviewDragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    PositionAdorner(e.GetPosition(adornedUIElement));
    OnAdornedUIElementPreviewDragOver(sender, e); // Call derived classes here <<<
    if (e.Handled) return; // to bypass base class behaviour
    HitTestResult hitTestResult = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(adornedUIElement, e.GetPosition(adornedUIElement));
    Control controlUnderMouse = hitTestResult.VisualHit.GetParentOfType<Control>();
    UpdateDragDropEffects(controlUnderMouse, e);
    e.Handled = true;
}

/// <summary>
/// Must be overidden in derived classes to call both the UpdateDropProperties and UpdateDragDropEffects methods to provide feedback for the current drag and drop operation.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender">The Control that the user dragged the mouse pointer over.</param>
/// <param name="e">The DragEventArgs object that contains arguments relevant to all drag and drop events.</param>
protected abstract void OnAdornedUIElementPreviewDragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e);
```

Then in my extended `ListBoxDragDropManager` class:

```
protected override void OnAdornedUIElementPreviewDragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    HitTestResult hitTestResult = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(AdornedUIElement, e.GetPosition(AdornedUIElement));
    ListBox listBoxUnderMouse = hitTestResult.VisualHit.GetParentOfType<ListBox>();
    if (listBoxUnderMouse != null && listBoxUnderMouse.AllowDrop)
    {
        UpdateDropProperties(ListBoxProperties.GetDragDropType(listBoxUnderMouse), ListBoxProperties.GetDropCommand(listBoxUnderMouse));
    }
    UpdateDragDropEffects(listBoxUnderMouse, e);
    e.Handled = true;  // This bypasses base class behaviour
}
```

Finally, it is used simply in the UI like so (the `RelativeSource` declarations and narrow width here make it seem worse than it is):

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Disc.Tracks, IsAsync=True}" SelectedItem="{Binding 
    Disc.Tracks.CurrentItem}" AllowDrop="True" Attached:ListBoxProperties.
    IsDragTarget="True" Attached:ListBoxProperties.DropCommand="{Binding 
    DataContext.DropTracks, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type 
    Views:ReleaseTracksView}}}" Attached:ListBoxProperties.DragDropTypes="{Binding 
    DataContext.DragDropTypes, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type 
    Views:ReleaseTracksView}}}" Attached:ListBoxProperties.DragEffects="{Binding 
    DataContext.DragEffects, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type 
    Views:ReleaseTracksView}}}">
```

I must be honest though... this was a *lot* of work. However, now that I can implement drag and drop operations with visual feedback just by setting a few properties, it totally seems worth it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is similar to what I have (minus the Telerik dragdropmanager). In the listbox case I would use a style for the items though. Then you can just get rid of all that hitbox testing. And there's the problem. I'd like to write something like <Setter Property="local:XYZTest.OnDrop" Value="OnXYZStyle" /> where OnXYZStyle is just a regular method handler. But when you do this the XAML loader crashes. So I put Value="{Binding OnXYZStyle, ElementName=root}" in there, but of course then I need a property called OnXYZStyle which returns a delegate.

Comment: If you use ICommands then you circumvent my original problem by returning the delegate via a property.

Comment: The `...DragDropManager` classes are my own custom classes, not Telerik's. I'm not really sure what you're saying that you'd change for your system, but I'm really happy with my system... I wouldn't change any of it... as far as I can see, every bit of code is required to fulfil some purpose. Good luck with your system.

Comment: Your system is basically very similar to mine. I think taking away all of the drag and drop stuff, I'd like to know whether I can do <Setter Property="local:XYZTest.XYZ" Value="OnDrop" /> . I know <ListBox local:XYZTest.XYZ="OnDrop" /> *does* work, but the Setter variant - which ought to do the same imo - *does not* work.

Comment: But what do you want to do in a `Trigger` when the object(s) is/are dropped? Surely that is the time to use code?

Comment: Ok, to clear this up I added the new code at the bottom of my question. The version as shown does not work. The XAML loader cannot convert the Value="OnXYZStyle" it seems. Now if you comment the first Setter and uncomment the Setter with the Binding then it works.

Comment: More curiously, I also need to have that SetABC method in there. It is never called, but without the code does not compile.

Comment: So the workaround I tried was to use the EventSetter instead which of course can handle a value of "OnXYZStyle". And that's how I arrived at this question, sorry for the long confusion.

Comment: Personally, I'd recommend starting again in a fresh project... add your code in bit by bit until you get one of these weird errors and then work out each one as you get it. Having to add methods that aren't called *just* to make code compile sounds like something has gone seriously wrong.

Comment: Nono, this actually IS a fresh project. And the reason why you need those methods is stated here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh965327.aspx .